# Scientific notation number from json_value is not matching another number

Tags: sql, json, oracle, scientific-notation

I'm having an issue where I need to match numbers from two tables.

My first table has the next number for example :

```
      AMOUNT
------------
123456789,92
```

My second table has:

```
MSGTOSEND_0182
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"amount":1.2345678992E8,"notes":"Nomina a Martin","transactionDetails":{"transactionChannelId":"_ach_enviada"}}
```

My query compares those with:

```
REPLACE(AMOUNT, ',', '.')) = REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount'), ',', '.'))
```

The result is null, there is not matching but if I parse the JSON in Notepad++ the numbers are the same.

Why aren't they matching in Oracle?

Comment: Please include your data as text, not images; and include the table definition. From the picture `amount` is already a number, both in the table and in the JSON, so why are you treating them as strings?

Comment: I edited it sorry, they are 2 numbers if i work them as numbers its happening the same, they dont match

Comment: [They do seem to match](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad7f0ffa3d837540c3047bdb306af751), as numbers or with your string manipulation (regardless of NLS setting). Are you sure it's that comparison, not another filter?

Comment: They are not matching, it`s the same number but those values are not matching.
I dont know what to do

Comment: Hmm, which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Although a simple number comparison [works in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad7f0ffa3d837540c3047bdb306af751):

```
select *
from zmt join po
on ZMT.AMOUNT = JSON_VALUE(PO.MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount' RETURNING NUMBER)
```

... it doesn't work in earlier versions - at least in 12cR1, where `json_value` was first introduced. With `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` set to `'.,'` (so period as decimal separator) your string version matches but the number version doesn't; and with `',.'` (so comma as decimal separator, as you seem to have) neither string or number version matches.

As a workaround you can get the JSON value as a string and then explicitly convert that to a number:

```
select *
from zmt join po
on ZMT.AMOUNT = TO_NUMBER(
                  JSON_VALUE(PO.MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount' RETURNING VARCHAR2(20)),
                  '9.9999999999EEEE', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')
```

... which *doesn't* work in 18c, because the JSON value is returned as a number (or a number formatted as a string, at least); which isn't unreasonable. But it's inconsistent between versions.

Comment: I tried the second option you say but it says :

01722. 00000 -  "invalid number".

I think when he tries to parse it to number again it broke

Comment: You still haven't said which version of Oracle you are using, which seems to be important here. You can run the `json_value()` part on its own to check the actual string you get back, and adjust as needed. (And if that doesn't help, add that, and your version info, to your question.)